# How to answer DS 160 question about not being granted a visa 6 years ago.

Tags: visas, usa, h1b-visas

I have an I-797 valid until next year, but my H1B visa will be expiring next month. I am travelling to India and completing a DS-160 for this.

Six years ago, my B1 visa application was refused. The officer didn't give me any documents; he just told me to try again and returned my passport.

On the DS 160 application, what i should answer to the question whether I have ever been refused a US visa? I didn't get any notice such as a 214B or 221G.

Should I say yes to the question, but that I don't know the reason for the refusal? I am confused to whether I should select yes or no.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's only 2 valid outcomes for a US Visa application - it can be approved, or it can be denied.

If you applied for a visa, and you did not receive a visa, then your application was rejected, and thus you should answer "Yes" to that question. What you've described is a little odd, but the simple fact is that answering "yes" is the only safe answer - the consular staff will know your application history, and answering "no" where you have previously applied will not look good!

Given that you are required to attend an interview anyway, the difference between answering yes and no is minimal.

Comment: Thank you so much Doc, sorry I don't have enough reputation to up vote your answer. I have a question through, in detail box what I should write. I remember only the year and place.

Comment: Write the truth!  If that's all you can remember, then write that.  If they need more details, they will ask during the interview.